# Java - input audio line doesn't have any controls

Tags: java, macos, controls, microphone

## Description

**Mac OS X 10.10.3**

Trying to control microphone (basically, setting system microphone volume to 100% + hoping to unmute it and trying to solve this problem https://discussions.apple.com/message/29309845#29309845).

*(code improved)*

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
public class MicMacMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mixer.Info microphone = null;
        for (Mixer.Info info : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
            System.out.println("Potential mixer: " + info.getName());
            if (info.getName().equals("Built-in Input")) {
                microphone = info;
            }
        }
        if (microphone == null) {
            System.out.println("Microphone not found");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        final Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(microphone);
        try {
            mixer.open();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        final Line lineIn;
        try {
            lineIn = mixer.getLine(mixer.getTargetLineInfo()[0]);
            lineIn.open();
            if (lineIn.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN)) {
                System.out.println("Gain supported");
            }
            final CompoundControl cc = (CompoundControl) lineIn.getControls()[0];
            final Control[] controls = cc.getMemberControls();
            for (final Control c : controls) {
                if (c instanceof FloatControl) {
                    System.out.println("BEFORE LINE_IN VOL = "
                                       + ((FloatControl) c).getValue());
                    ((FloatControl) c).setValue((float) 100 / 100);
                    System.out.println("AFTER LINE_IN VOL = "
                                       + ((FloatControl) c).getValue());
                }
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This code throws:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>   at MicMacMax.main(MicMacMax.java:24)

Which means there are no controls for the line.

## Help needed

- Are there bugs in my code?
- Would be really great if anyone can **test this code** on their machine and **provide feedback**. I would like to isolate the issue.
- Can it be connected with some kind of permissions issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried you code on my laptop and it worked(somewhat). It didn't give an error and it gave some specs about my computer However, It failed to find a microphone and I know that my laptop has a mic. the fact that you got an array out of bounds error at index 0 means that the array was empty which leads me to believe that your computer doesn't have a microphone or is damaged.

Also, here is the output on my laptop:

```
Potential mixer: Primary Sound Driver
Potential mixer: Speaker/HP (Realtek High Definition Audio)
Potential mixer: Primary Sound Capture Driver
Potential mixer: Microphone (Realtek High Defini
Potential mixer: Stereo Mix (Realtek High Defini
Potential mixer: Port Speaker/HP (Realtek High Defini
Potential mixer: Port Microphone (Realtek High Defini
Potential mixer: Port Stereo Mix (Realtek High Defini
Microphone not found
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Look at the line 24, it is not mic failing, it means Controls failed. No controls for mic. What OS do you have?

Comment: windows 8.1 but also checked on win 7. So, I think It may be because of your different OS as it may not support your mic. Try updating your drivers

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: You mic is not found, because it has different name from "Built-in Input", which is hardcoded in my code (because I try to solve a problem on Mac)

Comment: I think that your mic might not be supported. In that case, try updating your drivers

Comment: Well, I am using my mic every day, it seems that it is functioning absolutely properly.

Comment: Just posted a new answer, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it works for me However you may have to change the 100 to a different value if 100 is not the max volume for your mic.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
public class MicMacMax {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //pass volume level as parameter
    setMicrophoneVolume(100);
}
public static void setMicrophoneVolume(int value) {
    Mixer.Info[] mixerInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

    for (int i = 0; i < mixerInfos.length; i++) {
        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfos[i]);
        int maxLines = mixer.getMaxLines(Port.Info.MICROPHONE);
        Port lineIn = null;
        FloatControl volCtrl = null;
        if (maxLines > 0) {
            try {
                lineIn = (Port) mixer.getLine(Port.Info.MICROPHONE);
                lineIn.open();
                CompoundControl cc = (CompoundControl) lineIn.getControls()[0];
                Control[] controls = cc.getMemberControls();
                for (Control c : controls) {
                    if (c instanceof FloatControl) {
                        volCtrl = (FloatControl) c;
                        volCtrl.setValue((float) value / 100);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Hope this helped.